# How to add maven-checkstyle to existing project?

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I tried adding the `maven-checkstyle-plugin` to my project, but it does not produce any results:

```
<project>
....
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>google_checks.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

`mvn checkstyle:checkstyle` or `mvn checkstyle:check` results in:

```
[INFO] You have 0 Checkstyle violations.
```

Which is essentially not true, because I added violations explicit in my code.

So my guess is that checkstyle is not running the analyser properly over my code (that resides just normal in `/src/main/resources`).
What could I do?

Would I maybe have to add the `google_checks.xml` file explicit to my classpath??

Comment: Please show the full pom file... also complete output and not only a single line?

Comment: Please take a here a look ... :) 
[a maven-checkstyle-sample](https://github.com/sevntu-checkstyle/checkstyle-samples/blob/master/maven-project/pom.xml)

Comment: That's also useful [Setup CheckStyle in a Java project](https://www.manusobles.com/posts/setup-checkstyle-java)

Answer (score 0):

If the violations are warnings, you will need to add:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    [...]
        <configuration>
            <violationSeverity>warning</violationSeverity>
            <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
            [...]
```